# Which format to use to upload stylized subtitles to YouTube?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I would like to upload stylized subtitles to YouTube. Mainly, I need the ability to shift the position of the subtitles (sometimes, the default bottom position overlays some text in the video which results in both the text and the subtitles being very hard to read).

[This](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734698?hl=en) lists many formats but it seems only some arcane binary .scc format - that I have never heard about and have no idea how to produce - supports styles, as far as I can tell (beside EBU stl, which is even better). And I am not even sure it supports positioning.

Has anyone succeeded in this?

A plus would be if the subtitles could be produced in SubtitleEdit.